# Python, shap package: How to plot a grid of dependence plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, shap

I am trying to plot a grid of dependence plots from the `shap` package. Here is MWE code for an example of what I want:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,8, figsize=(16, 4), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k') # figsize=(width, height)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .5, wspace=.001)

axs = axs.ravel()

for i in range(10):

    axs[i].contourf(np.random.rand(12,12),5,cmap=plt.cm.Oranges)
    axs[i].set_title(str(250+i))

plt.show()
```

[image: An example layout of what I want]

Here is the code I have so far. A few things aren't working:

1. The figure size of my grid aren't impacted by my `figsize` arguments
2. My code plots bigger versions of my plots beneath the grid.
3. Only one of the dependence plots is showing in the grid.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,8, figsize=(4, 2))
axs = axs.ravel()

for b in X_test.columns[:3]:
    for a in X_test.columns[:3]:
        shap.dependence_plot((a, b), shap_interaction_values, X_test)
```

An image of what I am getting:
[image: What I am getting.]

Answer (score 8):

```py
import shap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = ...
shap_values = ...

columns = X.columns

# adjust nrows, ncols to fit all your columns
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(20, 14))
axes = axes.ravel()

for i, col in enumerate(columns):
    shap.dependence_plot(col, shap_values, X, ax=axes[i], show=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you - the [code](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/23eefa2f1cceea62ee27b758ac70a83a2af6bf7a/shap/plots/dependence.py) says that dependence_plot takes an optional parameter: ax

So you can make your subfigures and place your subsequent plots into that:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
shap.dependence_plot((a, b), shap_interaction_values, X_test, ax=ax1)
shap.dependence_plot((a, b), shap_interaction_values, X_test, ax=ax2)
```

In your case you can `zip()` the axes and the columns together.

I have not solved yet what to do in case of using `interaction_index` - in that case, you'll get all possible interaction_indexes heatmaps at the end of your figure, which looks very bad.

Edit: Ugly hack but it seems to do the deal - if you specify interaction_index for each of the dependence_plots then it will plot one colorbar for each plot into the last subplot, which looks awful.

I ended up manually deleting the axes (each colorbar is one additional axis) and then automatically readjusted the subplots:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, constrained_layout=True)
shap.dependence_plot((a, b), shap_interaction_values, X_test, ax=ax1)
shap.dependence_plot((a, b), shap_interaction_values, X_test, ax=ax2)
fig.axes[-1].remove()
fig.axes[-1].remove()
```

This will get rid of *all* colorbars, and constrained_layout=True will ensure that the last subfigure is redrawn correctly, without this parameter it will stay 'squished' to make space for the non-existent colorbars.