Multiple partial dependence plot with regression line in a grid
Basically, what I need is this but with the regression line:

The partial dependence plots that SHAP outputs, each one of them with a regression line, and plotted into a grid.
I know how to get multiple SHAP partial dependence plots on a grid, the code is something like this, taken from How to plot a grid of dependence plots?
def shap_dependence_plot_grid(cols, 
                              shap_values, 
                              X,    
                              interaction_index = None,
                              alpha = 0.75,
                              xmin = 'percentile(1)',
                              xmax = 'percentile(99)'):
    
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    cols: Either a list/array of column names or indices
    
    shap_values: Your shap values
    
    X: The feature data
    
    interaction_index: Column for interactions or 'auto' 
        (see help(shap.dependence_plot) for details)
    
    alpha: Alpha blending for the points
    
    xmin: Either None, a value or a string like 'percentile(1)'
    
    xmax: Either None, a value or a string like 'percentile(99)'
    
    
    Returns
    ----------
    A grid of plots with 3 columns and as many rows as necessary
    
    
    References
    ----------
    Partially inspired by 
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/65710424 (CC BY SA 4.0)
    
    '''
    
    # get the required number of rows
    nrows = math.ceil(len(cols) / 3)
    
    # create the grid of suplots
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(
        nrows = 6, 
        ncols = 1,
        figsize = (3, 6 + 3 * nrows))
    
    # Turn the axes into a 1d array
    axes = axes.ravel()
    
    # loop through the cols and their indices
    # plotting a shap.dependence_plot
    for i, col in enumerate(cols):
        
        shap.dependence_plot(col, 
            shap_values, 
            X,     
            interaction_index = interaction_index,
            alpha = alpha,
            xmin = xmin,
            xmax = xmax,
            ax=axes[i], 
            show=False)
        
    # adjust the layout
    fig.tight_layout(pad = 1)

        
    return fig

I also know how to add the regression line based on Add regression line to a shap.dependence_plot
import statsmodels.api as sm

idx = np.where(X.columns=="Age")[0][0]
x = X.iloc[:,idx]
y_sv = shap_values[:,idx]
lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y_sv, x, frac=.3)

_,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(*list(zip(*lowess)), color="red", )

shap.dependence_plot("Age", shap_values, X, ax=ax)

However, I can't seem to make both codes work, because of the axes and/or the loop. As far as my understanding of Python goes, the regression code is using the same ax to plot both figures at the same time, whereas the code for getting all the plots on a grid is using axis[i]. This is the code I'm trying to make work:
def shap_dependence_plot_grid(cols, 
                              shap_values, 
                              X,    
                              interaction_index = None,
                              alpha = 0.75,
                              xmin = 'percentile(1)',
                              xmax = 'percentile(99)'):
    
    
    # get the required number of rows
    nrows = math.ceil(len(cols) / 3)
    
    # create the grid of suplots
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(
        nrows = 6, 
        ncols = 1,
        figsize = (3, 6 + 3 * nrows))
    
    # Turn the axes into a 1d array
    #axes = axes.ravel()
    

    # loop through the cols and their indices
    
    # plotting a shap.dependence_plot
    for i, col in enumerate(cols):
        
        idx = np.where(X.columns==col)[0][0]
        x = X.iloc[:,idx]
        y_sv = shap_values.values[:,idx,1]
        lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess(y_sv, x, frac=.3)
        _,ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(*list(zip(*lowess)), color="red", )
        shap.dependence_plot(col, 
            shap_values.values[:,:,1], 
            X,     
            interaction_index = interaction_index,
            alpha = alpha,
            xmin = xmin,
            xmax = xmax,
            dot_size=3,
            color="#000",
            ax=axes[i], 
            show=False)
    
    
    # adjust the layout
    fig.tight_layout(pad = 3)

        
    return fig


Hi! A sample of the data you are working with or a toy example would make it much easier to reproduce your case, and thus help you!
